# SpringBoot 2.0 - FileSizeLimitExceededException even with correct parameters set

Tags: java, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I've set those parameters in my application.yml:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: -1
      max-request-size: -1
```

and when I run it from IDE it works fine. The problem starts when I try to run it along with spring cloud, netflix eureka, and zuul proxy. It behaves like there is no such paramteters. It always throws:

> "Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.",

Shall I set it somewhere else?

EDIT:
My bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  profiles: docker
  application:
    name: test-service
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 1
  zipkin:
    base-url: http://zipkin:9411/
  cloud:
      config:
        discovery:
          enabled: true
          service-id: config-server
        fail-fast: true
        retry:
          initial-interval: 2000
          max-interval: 10000
          multiplier: 2
          max-attempts: 10

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: test-service
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS

logging:
  file: ./logs/log.log
```

Comment: Do you also have a bootstrap.yml  ?

Comment: Looks to me as a classpath issue with different versions of spring boot.1) Check your version of spring cloud dependencies, they might be bringing in an older version of spring boot. 2) check your version of spring cloud is compatible with spring boot 2

Comment: if you are using maven as build system, you can us mvn dependency:tree command to see your effective pom

Comment: @Arnaud I've updated my post with bootstrap.yml

Comment: @AnilBachola Spring boot has version 2.0.4 and cloud is Finchley.RELEASE

Comment: Did you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887458/uploading-large-files-via-zuul

Comment: Try to put your parameters inside bootstrap.yml, or inside the config for this service in the config server.

Comment: I've tried with bootstrap.yml but i didn't do it in config server. I will check it :)

Comment: @Arnaud still the same :/

Comment: @AnilBachola did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and found the solution, post it here still anyone needs help after 3years.

If your traffic flow through the **Netflix Zuul edge service**, you should update the below properties in both Zuul and your file upload application service.

for spring boot **2**.x and above its

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```